# radio buttons not working in IE 9

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Hi there I have a site that uses radio button to select options. If you click the button itself it does not work (get selected), but does if you click the text below the button, any help would be appreciated.

BTW how would I apply a fix only to IE9 as all works fine in IE 6-8.

Is this a known issue with IE9?

Thanks very much

ok here is the code that fixed the problem for IE9 but now does not work for IE 8-6

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    $(function()
    {
        inClickFunc=false;

        var changeFunc = function()
        {
            if(!inClickFunc)
            {
                $(this).parent().click();
            }

            return false;
        };

        $("input[type=radio]").bind('change', changeFunc);
        $("input[type=radio]").bind('propertychange', changeFunc);

        $(".attinner").click(function()
        {
            inClickFunc=true;
            var input=$("input", this);

            $(".sub-values", $(this).parents(".middlecontent")).remove();

            if(input.attr("checked"))
            {
                input.attr("checked", false);
            }
            else
            {
                input.attr("checked", true);
                var div=this;

                $.get("/js/product_options.php", {product_id: 1130, value_id: $(input).attr("value")}, function(result)
                {
                    if(result)
                    {
                        $(div).parent().nextAll(".clear").eq(0).after(result);
                    }
                });
            }

            inClickFunc=false;
        });

        $('.sub-value').livequery('click', function()
        {
            $("input", this).attr("checked", true);
        });

        $("[name=product]").submit(function()
        {
            var submit=false;

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                url: '/js/validate_product.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    if(msg.length==0)
                    {
                        submit=true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        submit=false;
                        alert(msg);
                    }
                }
            });

            return submit;
        });

        /*$(".middlecontent").each(function() {
            $options = $(this).find('.attinner');

            if($options.length == 1)
            {
                $options.click()
            }
        });*/
    });
    -->
</script><h2>Size (Height x Width x Depth)</h2>
<div class="middlecontent">
                <div class="attribute-wide">
        <div class="attinner">
                                                    <input type="radio" title="Values" name="values[23]" class="required" value="5325"><div class="attvalue">
            1981mm x 686mm x 35mm<br>78" x 27" x 1.38"<br><span class="size-price">(£109.00)</span>         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                        <div class="attribute-wide">
        <div class="attinner">
                                                    <input type="radio" title="Values" name="values[23]" class="required" value="5324"><div class="attvalue">
            1981mm x 762mm x 35mm<br>78" x 30" x 1.38"<br><span class="size-price">(£109.00)</span>         </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: here is some code this has fixed the problem in IE9 but now does not work in IE 8-6

Comment: You know you can use `label`s to assign a clickable text to a radiobutton, without having to write a single line of Javascript? It will make your life easier, because you don't have to worry about event bubbling and all that stuff, you can just handle the click on the label.You're allowed to put the radiobutton inside the label too, so you can just display it as a block element to replace the `attinner` div you got now.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to allow a user to click both the text and the button is to use a label tag with raw HTML, there's no need to mess around with JavaScript or JQuery.

Try marking up your buttons like this:

```
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="account" value="radiobutton" />
<input type="radio" title="Values" name="values[23]" class="required" value="5324" id="unique_identifier">
<label for="unique_identifier">1981mm x 686mm x 35mm<br />78" x 27" x 1.38"<br /><span class="size-price">(£109.00)</span></label>
```

Comment: also dont forget to preselect radio buttons as single or one of part of a group.

Comment: Thanks for your thought will see if this remove of the javascript and using html and label works thanks very much